# Centering just the DIV instead of the sidebar too

Tags: css, html

I have a header, a sidebar, and a content div.

The Header is docked to the top and fixed there. The sidebar is fixed the to the left. Now I have 3/4 of the screen on the right free of space. I have a content div that I want to place there. It needs to be centered in that 3/4 space.

Here is my  code for the sidebar and content div.

CSS:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(225,225,225,0.2);
    height:100%;
}
#sidebarTop {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding:20px 50px;
    border-bottom:0.15em solid rgb(229,229,229);
    background: rgba(225,225,225,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset -10px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:100px;
    height:900px;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Here is my HTML code for sidebar and content div.

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebarTop">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    TEST
</div>
```

The problem comes here. What happens is that instead of ignoring the sidebar and pushing the content div to 100px down (margin-top:100px), it brings the side-bar down to the same level too.

My goal is to center that div both vertically and horizontally in that 3/4 of screen space left after the sidebar and the header fill the rest.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In the #content selector you could merge **margin** and **margin-top** in **margin: 100px auto;**.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to `#content`.

```
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:100px;
    height:900px;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

should be:

```
#content
{
    margin:100px auto 0;
    width:400px;
    height:900px;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 30px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 30px #fff;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px #fff;
    float:left;
}
```

---

### Updated:

**CSS**

```
html,
body
{
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#758;
}
#content
{
    margin-left:-50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50%;
    width:400px;
    height:900px;
    background:#758;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    "fixed" sidebar
</div>
<div id="content">
    "horizontally centered" content
</div>​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X5N9m/)**

---

### Update 2:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:300px;
    right:0;
    height:900px;
}
#content
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    background:#758;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    "fixed" sidebar
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        "horizontally centered" content
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/X5N9m/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That did do the trick but the centering problem still exists. Although I can control where I want to position the content div now as its not forcing the sidebar along with it, I still can't center it with the margin:0 auto thing.

Comment: I updated my answer. :) I hope this is what you were looking for, tho.

Comment: This is nearly perfect. Is it possible to center it using 'margin:0 auto' instead of using percentages? The thing with percentages is that it completely messes up when the browser is resized.

Comment: Although this wasn't the most efficient way of doing it, it still works, so thank you! Everyone else, thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can think of something better, please let's hear it. :) I continuously look for ways to make my coding more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try in this way:
CSS:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar {
    border: 2px solid yellow; /*Added to show the box-model*/

    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(225,225,225,0.2);
    height:100%;
}
#sidebarTop {
    border: 2px solid black; /*Added to show the box-model*/

    height:100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding:20px 50px;
    border-bottom:0.15em solid rgb(229,229,229);
    background: rgba(225,225,225,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset -10px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#foo {
    border: 2px solid pink; /*Added to show the box-model*/

    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 27%;
    width: 73%;
}
#content {
    border: 2px solid green; /*Added to show the box-model*/

    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    /*margin-top:100px;*/ /*this can be deleted*/
    height: 100%;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebarTop">
        ....
    </div>
</div>

<div id="foo">
    <div id="content">
        TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebarTop {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "center" tag like this:

```
<div id="content">
<center>
    TEST
</center>
</div>
```